# Как сделать админку в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Я захотел написать админку своему боту но я новичок и не нашел никакой нормальной инфы для написания админки. Какие средства надо знать для написания админ панели в нее должны входить фунции отправить сообщение конкретному пользователю или массовая рыссылка, логи всех юзеров.

Comment: А как должна выглядеть админка для бота в телеграмме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

зная (имея список, словарь, БД) id пользователя можно отправлять сообщения от имени бота таким образом:

```
# Функция отправки сообщения от имени бота одному пользователю (ввод id и сообщения)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['msgfrombot'])
def msg_from_bot(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите id пользователя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, msg_from_bot_1)

def msg_from_bot_1(message):
    global user_id
    user_id = message.text
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, msg_from_bot_2)

def msg_from_bot_2(message):
    bot.send_message(user_id, '{}'.format(message.text))
```

для отправки сразу всем пользователям используйте for

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что удивило меня больше: вопрос или то, что на него появился ответ :)

Comment: вопрос сам по себе двоякий, с одной стороны говорят про админку, а по функциям - несколько строк. а раз у меня есть пример кода почему не поделиться?